# Google Play Services won't work because Firebase creates another oath client ID

Tags: service, oauth, playback

My app has been published for a couple years and all was well, Google play services was working and the app was integrated with Firebase.  Then I upgraded to app signing, and in doing so somehow I managed to have the wrong OAuth client ID show up in the google_services.json file.  In the Firebase developer docs it says you can delete your Firebase project then create a new one, importing existing app.  When I do that it creates yet another OAuth client ID, ignoring the one in Game Play Services.
Signing in with Google works, but scores and times are not being posted to Leaderboards.  I want to continue using Firebase for analytics, dynamic links and app invites.   Does anyone know how to proceed to get back to having functioning leaderboards and achievements?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.  First, you'll know you have this issue if the OAuth client ID in your google_services.json file does not match the Oauth Client ID under "linked apps" in game play services.

The solution is to:
1)  Unlink your app in Firebase, by going to settings, integration, and clicking un-link.
2)  Next, go to the developer console and under game services, app details, you should be able to click through a link to see your app in the app console.  There you'll see the Oauth ID.  If it does not match the one in your google_services.json file, delete it.
3)  Go to "linked apps" in game services, and create another Oauth client ID by clicking "link another app".
4)  Once you have linked your app again, you should see a link that says "Add Firebase to your app".  Click that link to add Firebase, and follow the steps.
5)  Make sure to download the new google_services.json file into the app\ directory of your Android Studio project.
6)  Re-build your project and you should be all set.  Note that the Oauth client ID in your google_services.json file will now match the new one you created in the Developer Console.